# Highlighting Part of a Result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to highlight ONLY the variables: principal, rate, interest, year in the return statement of the compute function. It is required of me that **all styling must be in the CSS file only. No inline or internal stylesheets are allowed. All code must be in the JavaScript file only.** I have created the *highlight* class in CSS but this highlights the whole sentence and I don't know how to only highlight parts of a return statement without using inline.

Could someone please help/guide me to know how it's done cause I'm new to using these languages? Would be much appreciated.

Kindly find the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code below.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!--- On clicking the button it computes the interest by calling the compute() function --->
<button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button><br><br>
<!--- Show computation result --->
<span id="result" class = "highlight"></span>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
/* Highlights the result */
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
/* Function that computes and returns the result */
function compute()
{
    /* some code */
   
 return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="If you deposit "+principal+",\<br\>at an interest rate of "+rate+"%\<br\>You will receive an amount of "+interest+",\<br\>in the year "+year+"\<br\>";
}
```

Comment: Wrap your intended words in the innerHTML in a span with the highlight class. `document..getElementById("result").innerHTML="If you deposit <span class='highlight'>"+principal+"</span>,\<br\>at an interest rate of <span class='highlight'>"+rate+"</span>%\<br\>You will receive an amount of <span class='highlight'>"+interest+",</span>\<br\>in the year <span class='highlight'>"+year+"</span>\<br\>";`

Comment: Also, you are returning an assignment. I'm not sure if that's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you would need span-elements with the class highlight around you're variables. For semantics it might be better if the element with the id result is a p-element or something similar.

Also as @user1599011 pointed out, your Javascript needs to do something, it needs to execute a command, not return it.

A working solution:

```js
let principal = '1000';
let rate = '10';
let interest = '100';
let year = '2022';

/* Function that computes and returns the result */
function compute()
{
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= 'If you deposit <span class="highlight">' +principal+ '</span>, <br>at an interest rate of <span class="highlight">' +rate+ '%</span><br>You will receive an amount of <span class="highlight">' +interest+ '</span>, <br>in the year <span class="highlight">' +year+ '</span><br>';
}
```

```css
/* Highlights the result */
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!--- On clicking the button it computes the interest by calling the compute() function --->
<button onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
<!--- Show computation result --->
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have two questions. 1. Wouldn't using the span element around the variables be considered as inline stylesheets? 2. Could you please explain to me the difference between a function executing a command and returning it? Is one better than the other? Sorry for taking your time!

Comment: As for your first question. Right now we are just giving the span element a class like `<span class="highlight">`. With just this tag there still won't be any styling if you don't have a seperate stylesheet. So it's not inline styling. You're structure (html) and styling (css) are still seperated! After all the styling is still done in another document by saying the .highlight class needs to be a background: yellow;   Inline styling would be like defining the style in the html-tag like `<span style="background-color:yellow;">`  then we're mixing structure and styling.

Comment: The second question is a bit harder to explain in a few characters. In your example you want Javascript just to do something for you. The function needs to do its job, just execute the lines you've programmed and then it's finished. It doesnt need to return any value or message, just execute something.  An example where a return statement would be necessary is when you need to fill a variable with a result from a function for example. `function calcInterest(amount){ return amount * 0.1; }` and now you can fill a variable like that with `let interest = calcInterest(1000);` interest is 100 now.

Comment: Ok, got it! Truly can't thank you enough! And again, sorry for taking your time :)